# Sequential System of Equations

Tags: equation-solving, system

I’m trying to set up this system of equations that sequential feeds into itself. I have these 2 equations I’m running. I’m new to Mathematica so I have no idea how to even start this.

The basic idea is:

D0 -> G1 -> D1 -> …. Dt-1 -> Gt -> Dt  and I want to run this for some fix amount of periods.

where D0 is just some initial given value but everything after that is dependent upon the system. Can you guys offer me any advice?

Comment: `Nest`/`Fold` ?

Comment: I think you need to define your problem better, in the mathematical sense. Is `G(t)` a function that takes a state of the system `D(t)` at time `t` to the state at time `t+1`? Is `G(t)` known as a function of time? Is time a discrete variable (as your diagram seems to suggest) or is it continuous? In order to program effectively, in Mathematica or anything else, you (and the community here, if they are to help you) need to understand precisely the problem that you want to solve.

Comment: Yes, G(t) is a function of D(t-1),  so G(D(t-1)) and t is discrete.

Answer (score 3):

As commented, `Nest` or `Fold` might be applicable here, but there's a neat and underused function called `ComposeList` that does this elegantly. Here's an example of a function that takes the list of functions, the starting argument, and number of times to apply them in sequence, resulting in a list of results:

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := 2*x

fns = {f, g}

ComposeList[#1[[Mod[Range[#3], Length@#1, 1]]], #2] &[fns, z, 8]


(* {z, z^2, 2 z^2, 4 z^4, 8 z^4, 64 z^8, 128 z^8, 16384 z^16, 32768 z^16} *)
```

With three functions, etc.:

```
h[x_] := x/3 + 2

ComposeList[#1[[Mod[Range[#3], Length@#1, 1]]], #2] &[{f, g, h}, z, 5]

(* {z, z^2, 2 z^2, 2 + (2 z^2)/3, (2 + (2 z^2)/3)^2, 2 (2 + (2 z^2)/3)^2} *)
```